# How to upload video using AngularJs

Tags: php, html, angularjs, angular-moviemasher, moviemasher

I am using angular-moviemasher editor to my project. But I want to upload videos to the Moviemasher from my SQL database.

```
<input type="button" nv-file-select uploader="uploader" value="c://test.mp4" />
```

but I couldn't upload my video to the system. Actually, my target is If user clicks this button,'test.mp4' video should be upload. please give me an idea of how to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app='videomodule' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    <button ngf-select ng-model="files"  accept='video/*' >select video</button>
    <video controls ngf-src="files[0]" ngf-accept="'video/*'" autoplay></video>
</div>
```

.

```
angular.module('videomodule', ['ngFileUpload']).controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', function ($scope, Upload){
    }]);
```